# How to establish private connection from Azure function to on premises or to AWS SQS queue?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to create a Azure function that needs to read messages in the AWS SQS queue for our organisation.

Connectivity between Azure and AWS has to flow through on-premises network.

I found this post that seems to have Azure function extension that will for this to happen:-

[trigger-azure-functions-from-aws-sqs-queues-laveesh-bansal](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/trigger-azure-functions-from-aws-sqs-queues-laveesh-bansal)

Azure function seem to have following 3 types:-

Consumption plan

Premium plan

Dedicated plan

Should I choose Premium plan to allow private communication rather then going over the internet?

I would like to find out the answer to following 2 questions:-

What is the best way to establish the network connectivity?

How can I install the function extension mentioned in the above web link?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your security requirements.
Potentially, you'll need to create a vnet and connect it to on-prem via express route vpn.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options

You'll need to link the function outbound traffic via delegated subnet on the above vnet.

You'll only need to use the Premium plan if you want to use Private Endpoint to block inbound public traffic to your function, otherwise a standard plan should be enough.

The extension should just work once the function is able to connect to on-prem network